# Split k-fold where each fold of validation data doesn't include duplicates

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe `df`. The `df` contains 1,000 rows. Like below.

```
print(df)

                    id    class
0      0000799a2b2c42d       0
1      00042890562ff68       0
2      0005364cdcb8e5b       0
3      0007a5a46901c56       0
4      0009283e145448e       0
...                ...     ...
995    04309a8361c5a9e       0
996    0430bde854b470e       0
997    0431c56b712b9a5       1
998    043580af9803e8c       0
999    043733a88bfde0c       0
```

And it has 950 data as `class 0` and 50 data as `class 1`.

Now I want to add one more column as `fold`, like below.

```
                    id    class  fold
0      0000799a2b2c42d       0     0
1      00042890562ff68       0     0
2      0005364cdcb8e5b       0     0
3      0007a5a46901c56       0     0
4      0009283e145448e       0     0
...                ...     ...   ...
995    04309a8361c5a9e       0     4
996    0430bde854b470e       0     4
997    0431c56b712b9a5       1     4
998    043580af9803e8c       0     4
999    043733a88bfde0c       0     4
```

where the `fold` column contains 5 folds(0,1,2,3,4). And each fold has 200 data, where 190 data as `class 0` and 10 data as `class 1`(by which means preserving the percentage of samples for each `class`).

I've tried `StratifiedShuffleSplit` from `sklearn.model_selection`, like below.

```
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_split=5, random_state=2021, test_size = 0.2)
for _, val_index in sss.split(df.id, df.class):
    ....
```

Then I regard every list of `val_index` as one specific fold, but it ends up giving me duplicates in each `val_index`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your question is unclear; you say you want each *val*-set to contain non-duplicates, while as evidence that this does not happen you refer to *train* folds. By definition, in k-fold CV, each sample will be in (k-1) *training* folds and only in 1 *validation* fold; duplicates do not exist in *validation* folds.

Comment: It is also not clear why you append your train & test indices, which is not the correct way of using k-fold CV; that way, after the for-loop, you will simply end up with the whole dataset in both `train_indexes` and `test_indexes`, which is not the point.

Comment: Edited, I hope this description could be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a kfold used for cross validation, not a train test split. You can use `StratifiedKFold`, for example your dataset is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : np.random.randint(1,1e5,1000),
'class' :np.random.binomial(1,0.1,1000)})
df['fold'] = np.NaN
```

We use the kfold, iterate through like you did and assign the fold number:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True)
for fold, [train,test] in enumerate(skf.split(df,df['class'])):
    df.loc[test,"fold"] = fold
```

End product:

```
pd.crosstab(df['fold'],df['class'])

class    0   1
fold          
0.0    182  18
1.0    182  18
2.0    182  18
3.0    182  18
4.0    181  19
```